# FIll color affects text in Tikz ladder diagram block symbols

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm new to Tikz and I'm trying to illustrate a PLC program using the [`circuit.ladder`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ladder) library. I want to color the blocks in a light blue color (since that resembles the color they have in the programming environment). But when setting the fill color and fill opacity, it makes the text appear transparent as well. I tried setting the `text opacity=1`since that should make the text opaque again, but it doesn't seem to work for some reason. Reading the library docs, I find info on how to color the text and block lines, but nothing about fill colors.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[english, 11pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.plc.ladder}
\usepackage{xstring} %To be able to use underscores in node texts

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit plc ladder,thin,y=0.5cm]
            \tiny
            \draw(0,0) 
                to [block={fill=blue,
                        symbol color=black,
                        fill opacity=0.5, 
                        text opacity=1,
                        info=fbName,
                        inputs={input},
                        outputs={output},
                        symbol={FB\textunderscore Type},
                        name = block, 
                        minimum width=6\ladderskip
                        }]
                ++(3,0); 

            \draw (block.input 1) -- +(-0.2,0)
                  (block.output 1) -- +(0.2,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Instead of transparency, a lighter shade of a color is easier done by using the `xcolor` interface and just setting `fill=blue!50`. The text parts seem to be done by `\pgftext` which is not a proper node and that's probably why text opacity fails.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks for the tip! You are probably right about the text too, allthough the `preaction`-workaround in the answer did the trick for me. Is that something that do work for `\pgftext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is not clear to me why `fill opacity` also affects the symbol text here, you could circumvent this effect by using a `preaction`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.plc.ladder}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit plc ladder, thin, y=0.5cm]
        \tiny
        \draw(0,0) 
            to[block={
                preaction={
                    fill=blue,
                    fill opacity=0.5,
                },
                info=fbName,
                inputs={input},
                outputs={output},
                symbol={FB\textunderscore Type},
                name=block, 
                minimum width=6\ladderskip
            }]
            ++(3,0); 

        \draw (block.input 1) -- +(-0.2,0)
              (block.output 1) -- +(0.2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also just use `fill=blue!50` without additionally stating a `fill opacity` as suggested in the comments.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you for this!